# Clip the bezier path itself

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How can we draw or animate on, using CAKeyframeAnimation, only part of a bezier path.
Say I have a bezier path my layer wants to move along, but I want my layer just move to a middle point of the path, how can I do that?

If we can get a sub path of a bezier path (by specifying the proportion), or clip a path, this problem will be solved.